# how to customize eclipse-rcp application's look and feel?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Use presentation solution can only change the look&feel of Views and Editors,
Can I change the look&feel of swt widgets, such as Tree, Table , TextInput ...and the background-color of all the gray panels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the e4's CSS engine to render the elements. It works well with 3.x as well.